# Where to place jaxb.properties when my pojos are spread over many different packages

Tags: java, properties, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm following [this official example](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime003.htm) on how to use Eclipse Link Moxy to transform my XML Node into my model class, so I have the following java code:

```
    byte[] bytes = getBytesIn("AW33.xml");
    Element rootnode = ConversionTool.byteArrayToDOMElement(bytes);

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    String bindingsFileName = ConversionTool.getBindingsFileName(rootnode);
    InputStream iStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("conversion/bindings/" + bindingsFileName);

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);

    Class<?> messageClass = ConversionTool.getMessageClass(rootnode);

    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{messageClass}, properties);
```

Like many other developers I ran into the trouble where you have to create a `jaxb.properties` file to support the property `eclipselink.oxm.metadata-source`.

If I place this file in the exact same package (but under /src/main/resources) as my `messageClass` it works, otherwise I get the well-known error:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.oxm.metadata-source" is not supported
```

The thing is that my model classes are spread over a hierarchy of packages, for instance:

```
a.b.c1
a.b.c2
a.b.c3
```

If I place it in the furthest common package, i.e. `a.b` it doesn't work.

So where do I place this file is this case?

Or is there a better way to create the JAXBContext in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If your are using

```
public static JAXBContext newInstance( Class[] classesToBeBound, Map<String,?> properties )
```

constructor. The **jaxb.properties** has to be placed in one of the packages there your model classes are placed.

For example, in this case

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(pkg1.Class1.class, pkg2.Class2.class);
```

you can place **jabx.properties** in **pkg1** package or **pkg2** package.

If you use Maven it has to be placed under **src/main/resources**, not under **src/main/java**.

I see that in your code you pass only one class to JAXBContext constructor. You have to pass all your classes there. Alternatively, you can use package based JAXBContext constructor and pass your packages there like this:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("pkg1:pkg2");
```

Again, **jaxb.properties** has to be in **pkg1** or **pkg2**.

Comment: I realize that, but I have hundreds of subpackages, and I determine which jaxb-class I have to deal with dynamically, so I'd have to place a jaxb.properties file under each of these subpackages. But that doesn't seem like a very smart thing to do.

I found that if I create an empty class under the common package, i.e. a.b, for instance Dummy.java, and I pass that class along to the newInstance() method, it serves as a work around to find the jaxb.properties in /src/main/resources/a/b.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a work around for this. If you create an empty class, in my case for instance, `a.b.Dummy`, and you pass that class along to the newInstance() method, like this:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{messageClass, Dummy.class}, properties);
```

MOXy will also look for the *jaxb.properties* file inside `/src/main/resources/a/b`, so you only have to place that file there. Or anywhere that matches your Dummy class's package. For instance, if your dummy class is under `my.company.app.model` then place *jaxb.properties* under `/src/main/resources/my/company/app/model`.